# How to use a C/C++ library (like NCurses) in Haxe

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, ncurses, haxe, curses

I have a cli written in Haxe and compiled to a binary via C++ (hxcpp). I would like to use ncurses in it. I have worked with ncurses in C and I've worked with JS externs in Haxe but I'm can't figure out the Haxe/C++ documentation to connection the two together.

I haven't used much more of the HXCPP compiler than the basic haxe command (ie not build files etc), à la:

```
haxe -lib somelib -cp src --cpp bin/cpp path.to.Main
```

Basically, I can work with all custom code, but am struggling on externals. So I'm not entirely sure how many steps I am missing towards my goal.  But I can see a few major obstacles.

1. How to include ncurses in the build? ie. `cc -lncurses -o out [etc...]` in a Makefile.
2. How to include the proper externs to allow Haxe to compile at all without error. All the extern examples I see involve a class/namespace but NCurses functions don't have a class or namespace. I haven't found any documentation for a bare extern function.
3. Then of course the basics of including the headers properly (or the haxe compilation equivalent) in my actual Haxe code.

I know this is basically asking for a mini-tutorial, but I can't find examples or documentation that I can put together to accomplish this specific goal.

Thanks for any help you can lend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HXCPP uses an [xml-based build system](https://haxe.org/manual/target-cpp-file-format.html). When you launch `haxe -cp src --cpp bin/cpp path.to.Main`:

1. Haxe files are transpiled to C++ and a `Build.xml` is produced in the output directory, i.e. `bin/cpp/Build.xml`;
2. everything is then built by HXCPP, merging the newly generated project `Build.xml` with the [global default xml definitions](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/tree/master/toolchain) and then calling the compiler toolchain(s).

You can inject compiler flags, libraries to link, *includes* directories, etc., through the `@:buildXml` metadata, [as described on the manual](https://haxe.org/manual/target-cpp-build-environment.html#defining-via-@buildxml-metadata):

```
@:buildXml("
    <target id='haxe'>
       <lib name='-lncurses' if='linux'/>
       <lib name='ncurses.lib' if='windows'/>
    </target>
")
class Main{ ...
```

These tags will be appended to the project `Build.xml`. [The `haxe` target is the default target](https://haxe.org/manual/target-cpp-build_xml-HaxeTarget.html). Keep in mind that every toolchain (MSVC, gcc, Xcode, etc.) has its own syntax. You can see examples in the [build.xml of cross-platform low-level projects like Systools](https://github.com/waneck/systools/blob/master/project/build.xml) or [Lime](https://github.com/haxelime/lime/blob/develop/project/Build.xml).

You can add `-D HXCPP_VERBOSE` to the haxe command line to see which commands are actually launched: `haxe -D HXCPP_VERBOSE -cp src --cpp bin/cpp path.to.Main`.

As for externs, the simpler case is:

1. you write your C++ code, with #includes and everything needed, inside a `@:cppFileCode()` block; everything you write here is pasted as-is in the generated cpp file;
2. you mark one of your haxe functions, defined on one of the haxe classes, as `@:native("nameOfTheCppFunction")`, and the build system will join them together.

```
    @:cppFileCode("
        #include <ncurses.h>

        void nativeCppTest(){
             /* here goes your ncurses code */
             return;
        }
    ")

    class Main{
        public static function main()
        {
            myCppTest();
        }

        @:native("nativeCppTest")
        extern static function myCppTest():Void;
    }
```

If you open the generated file (in this case `bin/cpp/src/Main.cpp`) you'll see that the haxe `myCppTest()` call is changed to its native version `nativeCppTest()`.

If you would like to pass function arguments, and receive return values, you'll have to wrap those [using the `cpp.*` standard library types](https://api.haxe.org/cpp/index.html). For example:

```
    @:cppFileCode("
        #include <ncurses.h>

        void nativeCppTest(const char* myString){
             /* here goes your ncurses code */
             return;
        }
    ")

    class Main{
        public static function main()
        {
            myCppTest("print this");
        }

        @:native("nativeCppTest")
        extern static function myCppTest(myString:cpp.ConstCharStar):Void;
    }
```

Some of the conversions will be automatic (like, in this case, from a constant string to ConstCharStar), some will require an explicit `cast`; if you need to pass pointers to the C++ code, you can get it via `cpp.RawConstPointer.addressOf(<haxe object>)` (or `RawPointer` if not const):

```
    public static function main()
    {
        var myString:String = "print this";
        myCppTest(cast cpp.RawConstPointer.addressOf(myString));
    }
```

Useful references:

- [C++ Magic by Hugh Sanderson](https://haxe.io/roundups/wwx/c++-magic/)
- [C++ extern example, everything in one file (MiniMP3 project)](https://github.com/LogicInteractive/MiniMP3.hx/blob/main/src/MiniMP3.hx)

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! Seeing it all put together makes the documentation make much more sense now. This is such a helpful example!